AWS EC2 instance receiving high number (20/second) of incoming requests from other AWS EC2 instances
I recently spun up a Django server (via Gunicorn) on an AWS EC2 instance with Docker.
After setting up Grafana/Loki, pointing my attention to the logs, I saw something odd. I'm getting up to 20 requests per second to three URL paths:
/check/site /check/squared-a /check/ha-a
I have received over 2500 of these requests in under 15 minutes. After investigating, it seems that the source ip addresses are all from AWS EC2 instances, scattered throughout all the AWS regions. Basically no one is using the application the server is built for (<5 downloads for the mobile app).
I don't have a lot of experience with AWS, so am I correct in assuming this is not normal?
Grafana chart over 9 minutes
These URLs are not relevant to my application (it is brand new and these URLs have never been real routes).

Random requests are completely normal on a web server.
